# How do I reduce each set of duplicates to one entry?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

Below is a sample from one of my MS Access tables.

There are 4 rows/records for 2001-7501. I would like this simply reduced to one entry.

I tried the Group By First option but it did not work.

A better other option is to 'ConcatRelated' the "Manufacturer" and "Manufacturer Part Number" entries into a single record delimited with ";". These two columns are causing all the duplicates.

```
DEVICE      Description                        Manufacturer   Manufacturer Part Number   Std Material Cost    OnHandQty   RoHS
2001-7500   CAP,1UF,10%,X7R,16V,SMD,1206       AVX            1206YC105KAT2A             0.018  9104          ROHS6       E0
2001-7501   CAP,470PF,20%,X7R,2000V,SMD,1206   AVX            1206GC471KAT1A             0.0266 7178          ROH6        E0
2001-7501   CAP,470PF,20%,X7R,2000V,SMD,1206   AVX            1206GC471MAT1A             0.0266 7178          ROHS6       E0
2001-7501   CAP,470PF,20%,X7R,2000V,SMD,1206   VENKEL         C1206X7R202-471KNE         0.0266 7178          ROHS6       E0
2001-7501   CAP,470PF,20%,X7R,2000V,SMD,1206   VENKEL         C1206X7R202-471MNE         0.0266 7178          ROHS6       E0
2001-7502   CAP,0.1UF,20%,X7R,16V,SMD,0603     AVX            0603YC104KAT2A             0.0021 4185          ROHS6       E0
2001-7502   CAP,0.1UF,20%,X7R,16V,SMD,0603     AVX            0603YC104MAT2A             0.0021 4185          ROHS6       E0
2001-7502   CAP,0.1UF,20%,X7R,16V,SMD,0603     KEMET          C0603C104M4RACTU           0.0021 4185          ROHS6       E0
2001-7504   CAP,10NF,10%,X7R,100V,SMD 0603     AVX            06031C103KAT2A             0.0039 0             ROHS6       E0
2001-7504   CAP,10NF,10%,X7R,100V,SMD 0603     KEMET          C0603C103K1RACTU           0.0039 0             ROHS6       E0
2001-7505   CAP,1NF,10%,X7R,100V,SMD           AVX            06031C102KAT2A             0.0043 6373          ROHS6       E0
2001-7505   CAP,1NF,10%,X7R,100V,SMD           KEMET          C0603C102K1RACTU           0.0043 6373          ROHS6       E0
2001-7506   CAP,100PF,20%,NPO,10V,SMD,0603     AVX            0603ZC101MAT2A             0.025  5044          ROHS6       E0
```

Comment: It looks to me as if you should have two tables, one for  "Manufacturer" and "Manufacturer Part Number" and another for the rest of the fields. It is almost never a good idea to store multiple entries in a single field.

Comment: Hi, and **welcome to StackOverflow**!  I have formatted the table in your question to make it easier to read.  In the future, if you have code or data to display, you can make it more readable by converting tabs to spaces and indenting it so it displays as code.  Thanks :)

Comment: Ideally, your database structure should be as [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) as possible.  Often the reason why a database is not properly normalized is because of application constraints.  What is the big picture problem you are trying to solve?  The direction you are trying to go is *worse* in terms of database maintenance.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got help from a colleage and have it working the way I wanted it.